# What to do in Box-Jenkins framework when time series has deterministic trend and seasonality?

Tags: time-series, self-study, stationarity, seasonality, trend

I'm self-studying time series and I'm puzzled by apparent lack of consistency between :

- the "classical" decomposition of time-series
- and the Box-Jenkins methodology.

Concerning the classical decomposition, you will find that a time-series can be decomposed into many components, including a :

- deterministic trend
- stochastic trend (that is, a unit root)
- seasonal component
- some other forms of periodicity that are not seasonal (like Kitchin and Juglar economic cycles)
- a residual or a stationary component

When it comes to Box-Jenkins however, it seems that only four combinations of the latter components are considered :

- the series is **stationary**
- the series is **Trend Stationary (TS)** (Deterministic Trend) and you should de-trend to stationarize
- the series is **Difference Stationary** (DS) (stochastic trend = unit root) and you should differentiate the series at order of integration (**ARIMA case**)
- the series is **DS** but also **exposes some seasonality**, so you must difference the series two times : first to filter out the seasonality, and secondly to filter out the unit root (**SARIMA case**)

However, it seems that Box-Jenkins makes no particular case for a time series that has both :

- a **deterministic trend** (as for Trend Stationary series)
- and a **seasonal component**

So is the Box-Jenkins framework "incomplete" and does not take into account this specific case ? Or does it mean that seasonal components are just seen as a particular type of deterministic trend ?

Comment: Are you sure? If I remember correctly the whole chapter 9 in the original Box-Jenkins was about seasonal models with trends, in particular their model for the ['Series G' airline data](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc44a.htm) in chapter 9.2.

Comment: Thanks for the landmark. If your references are directly from the classic of Box-Jenkins, then indeed I might have missed it. I usually use textbooks made for beginners or intermediate, because I fear that the original books from top-notch specialists might be too complex for me.